# How to send notification from microservice to asp.net core's SignalRHub

Tags: signalr, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to make some of my webapp features realtime. So i started with signalR.For any database changes i want to show new data on client realtime. I have seen two approach of doing this.

- The first way is in which function i am changing the data then call
  the signalrhub to send the new data to all connected client. and
- the other process is by triggering "sql server dependency or sql server table dependency" and send notification to connected client and and client will reload the data after getting the notification.

But there is a microservice that is constantly fetching data and changing the value from database which is not integrate with the core asp.net core project. Now i want to show the data change by the microservice. In that manner i have to call the signalr hub from the microservice. My question is "is that possible? if possible then how?".

Comment: `Now i want to show the data change by the microservice.` Do you mean that showing real-time updates to web client application(s) that consume your microservice? if so, you can implement real-time notification functionality in web client application rather than in that microservice. As we know, to push/send notification(s) to clients, we need to call method/function that is defined on client application from hub, if you implement notification functionality in microservice, client application may not define methods for being invoked by hub and receiving messages.

Comment: Besides, if you indeed want to implement it within your microservice, you can install SignalR client library (if it provide corresponding client library for the language you used to build microservice) and make your microservice also act as a SignalR client to communicate with hub and other connected clients.

Comment: No the client does not retrieve any data its only change the data in database. The main project has api to show the data

Comment: generally we call the signalr hub context when changing some data in controller. now i want to call that hub context in my service application also to send notification to the client. the service has no api endpoint.

Comment: `now i want to call that hub context in my service application also to send notification to the client.` As I mentioned, to achieve that, you may need to  install SignalR client library and make your service also act as a SignalR client to communicate with hub and other connected clients.

Comment: have you consider sqldependency?

Comment: no sqldependency and sql table dependency has many performance degradation